# Getting error while setting up DSN with Dremio odbc driver on Debian 10

Tags: odbc, unixodbc, debian-based, dremio, debian-packaging

I got into a fresh debian 10 environment with following command

```
 docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash debian:10
```

Inside the container I am installing various utilities and tools with:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install -y odbcinst1debian2 libodbc1 odbcinst unixodbc wget alien
```

Then inside /opt directory, I am installing rpm file latest dremio odbc driver using:

```
cd opt
wget https://download.dremio.com/odbc-driver/1.5.3.1000_2/dremio-odbc-1.5.3.1000-2.x86_64.rpm
```

After this I am converting rpm to deb using alien and then installing the driver using:

```
alien dremio-odbc-1.5.3.1000-2.x86_64.rpm
dpkg -i dremio-odbc_1.5.3.1000-2_amd64.deb
```

output -

```
Selecting previously unselected package dremio-odbc.
(Reading database ... 18427 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dremio-odbc_1.5.3.1000-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dremio-odbc (1.5.3.1000-2) ...
Setting up dremio-odbc (1.5.3.1000-2) ...
```

I can confirm the installation using following commands:

```
root@580b59f527a2:/opt# find / -name *libdrillodbc_sb64.so*
/opt/dremio-odbc/lib64/libdrillodbc_sb64.so
```

Now in order to test connection using DSN I am modifying /etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini files as follow:

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[DremioODBC]
Description=Dremio ODBC Driver(64-bit)
Driver=/opt/dremio-odbc/lib64/libdrillodbc_sb64.so
UsageCount=1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
    [ODBC Data Sources]
    DremioODBC=Dremio ODBC Driver 64-bit

    [DremioODBC]
    Description=Dremio ODBC Driver (64-bit) DSN
    Driver=/opt/dremio-odbc/lib64/libdrillodbc_sb64.so
    ConnectionType=Direct
    HOST=[host]
    PORT=[port]
    AuthenticationType=Plain
    UID=[userid]
    PWD=[password]
    Catalog=DREMIO
```

Now while testing the connection I am getting following error:

```
root@580b59f527a2:/opt# isql -v DremioODBC
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/dremio-odbc/lib64/libdrillodbc_sb64.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Even though the libdrillodbc_sb64.so file is present I am not able to make connection.

I also tried to give permission to libdrillodbc_sb64.so but still getting same error again.

ldd command gives following output:

```
root@580b59f527a2:/opt/dremio-odbc/lib64# ldd /opt/dremio-odbc/lib64/libdrillodbc_sb64.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff02de3000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f710fb22000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f710fb1d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f710fafc000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => not found
        libkrb5support.so.0 => not found
        libkrb5.so.3 => not found
        libk5crypto.so.3 => not found
        libatomic.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1 (0x00007f710faf0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f710f96d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f710f953000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f710f792000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7112c0f000)
```

ODBC version:

```
root@580b59f527a2:/opt# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Can anyone let me know if i am missing anything.

I have referred https://community.dremio.com/t/error-install-odbc-driver-on-ubuntu-18/4655

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by adding following commands before testing connection:

```
apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2
apt-get install -y libkrb5-3
apt-get install -y libatomic1
```